# Why is csv.writer removing leading zeroes?

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to write numeric strings to a CSV file. Some of the strings have leading zeroes, and when the strings are written to the file, the leading zeroes disappear. Why is this happening, and how do I prevent it?

Sample code:

```
import csv

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    row = ("01", "02", "03")
    writer.writerow(row)
```

When I open `output.csv`, the values that have been written appear as `1,2,3`, not `01,02,03`.
I am using Python 2.7.9 on Windows 10 Pro, if that is relevant to the issue.

EDIT: It appears the issue comes from the fact that I am opening the CSV file with Excel, which tries to do its own thing with the contents of the file.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using binary mode? Also, what are you opening the csv with? Excel will automatically convert the values to numbers hence removing the leading 0s. I'm getting expected output in notepad etc, but can replicate with cells A1->A3 containing 1->3 in Excel

Comment: FWIW, with Python 2.7.10 on Windows it gives me correct output with leading zeroes: `01,02,03` as the only line of `output.csv`.

Comment: Could not replicate, file contains zeroes for me.

Comment: I'm using binary mode because otherwise `csv.writer` skips lines. And yes, I am opening the csv with Excel. If that's the source of the problem, is there a way to keep Excel from automatically converting the values to numbers?

Comment: @NickA opening in binary mode is an alternative to opening with the keyword: `newline=''`, which I'm not sure is available in 2.x

Comment: Configure `csv` to quote everything, that would probably do it.

Comment: Edit your question, include the text of the csv file that produces the problem you are seeing, and the text of the output csv file. If you are examining the output in Excel, be aware it silently converts text it thinks are numbers into actual numbers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How do I do that? Do I put escaped quotes inside the string?

Comment: Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), they explain how to configure it.

Comment: there's a parameter you can set when registering your own dialect called [`csv.QUOTE_ALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL)

Comment: @jonrsharpe when you open a quote'd string Excel still parses to number, i.e., if the csv contained `"01","02","03"` *exactly* it would still come out as `1,2,3`

Comment: @NickA wow, what [*"useless garbage"*](https://superuser.com/questions/234997/how-can-i-stop-excel-from-eating-my-delicious-csv-files-and-excreting-useless-da)!

Comment: @jonrsharpe *however* you can prepend an `=` so it is `="01",="02",="03"` and it will work correctly

Comment: @NickA Do I prepend the `=` in Python or in a CSV editor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Microsoft Excel (2013 at least), will convert values in csv files to numbers if they are fully numerical `01` for example, to get around this you can force Excel to parse the value as a string.

You can use the following:

```
row = tuple("=\"" + r + "\"" for r in row)
```

to prepend `="` and append `"` to each element, effectively turning it into an Excel string.

```
>>> row = ("01", "02", "03")
>>> row = tuple("=\"" + r + "\"" for r in row)
>>> row
('="01"', '="02"', '="03"')
```

This will appear as `="01",="02",="03"` in the csv and be parsed correctly by Excel.

Of course this will only work if no double quotes appear within your values.

Comment: Nope, no double quotes, just digits 0-9. Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar requirement but I don't want to show double quotes in excel. It should be `01, 02, 03`.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's a problem caused by Excel parsing. Probably better to just format the text in Excel after opening the file.

Assuming it's a fixed length value, you can format it using =Text(cell, "000000"), where # of zero is the length of your value.